# Python: How do I separate a mix of strings and integers from a csv?

Tags: python, list, split

```
import os
import csv
import pandas as pd
import itertools


data = r"C:\Users\chase\Documents\Exercise\MA Exercise_20190328-2"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(data):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            print(os.path.join(root, file))

    df = open("PikesPeak_Males.txt", "r")
    if df.mode == "r":
        contents = df.read()
        print(contents)

    with open("PikesPeak_Males.txt", "r") as in_file:
        stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
        lines = (line.split(",") for line in stripped if line)
        with open("PikesPeak_Males.csv", "w") as out_file:
            writer = csv.writer(out_file)
            writer.writerow(("Place", "Div/Tot", "Number", "Name", "Age", "Hometown", "Gun Time", "Net Time", "Pace"))
            writer.writerows(lines)
```

So I have a dataset of running times for Racers. I converted the text file to a `csv` however, I want to split all the data into the following columns "Place", "Div/Tot", "Number", etc... But I am not sure how to do it as there isn't any commas or features to split the lines by.  The main goal is to calculate the mean running time of the racers.
This is how it looks now:
[image]

Example of how I want my csv to look:

[image]
[PikesPeak_Male.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGDUb.jpg)

[PikesPeakData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5U22.jpg)

Comment: "***Example of how I want my csv to look:***": How does it look now? Where's the csv sample ?

Comment: Please provide the current format of the text file you wish to parse, prior to its conversion to csv.

Comment: what does `PikesPeak_Males.txt` look like ?

Comment: how can I share a text file on here?

Comment: Place Div/Tot Num Name Ag Hometown Gun Tim Net Tim Pace
1 1/48 9 Joshua Kemei 22 Kenya . 28:48 28:47# 4:38
2 2/48 35 George Kirwa Misoi 22 Kenya . 29:11 29:10# 4:42
3 3/48 3 Jacob Frey 24 Oakton VA 29:38 29:37# 4:46
4 1/96 49 Gurmessa Kumsa 27 Oxon Hill MD 29:46 29:46# 4:48
5 4/48 31 Mike Baird 24 Ardmore PA 30:31 30:30 4:55

Comment: just copy paste the first few lines and paste them here making sure that formatting is not lost

Comment: just added the photo of the format under PikesPeakMale.txt  you can click and view it.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) - [mcve]

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/41d0v8yfq67jrqw/PikesPeak_Males.txt?dl=0

Comment: I added the text file to my dropbox so you may access it.

Answer (score 0):

Check what are the separators in the .txt file. If they are tabs use tabs as separator when reading the csv:

```
pd.read_csv("filename.csv", header=None, delimiter=r"\t")
```

If separators are multiples of spaces first make one pass over the .txt file to convert multiples of spaces to single space or some other character ("\t",",",...) and then use the chosen character as a separator.